# How can I fix this Firebase keeps giving me this error Paths must not contain // in them., null, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid path

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Exception has occurred.
PlatformException (PlatformException(error, Invalid path (cart//Cart). Paths must not contain // in them., null, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid path (cart//Cart). Paths must not contain // in them.

```
class ProductPage extends StatefulWidget {
  String productId;     //  <<<=====================procuctId
  final String shopname;
  final String title;
  ProductPage({this.shopname, this.title, this.productId});

  @override
  _ProductPageState createState() => _ProductPageState();
}

CollectionReference productsRef = Firestore.instance.collection("MyShop");
CollectionReference cartRef = Firestore.instance.collection("cart");

class _ProductPageState extends State<ProductPage> {
  String prodname = "";
  AuthMethods _auth = AuthMethods();
  String myid = "";     //          <<<=====================myid(uid)
  String nickname = "";
  String name;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _auth.getCurrentUser().then((user) async {
      setState(() {
        myid = user.uid;
        name = user.displayName;
      });
    });
  }

  String _selectedProductSize = "0";

  Future _addToCart() {
    return cartRef
        .document(myid)     //  <<<=====================to Firestore
        .collection("Cart")
        .document(widget.productId)
        .setData({
      "myid": myid,
      "productname": widget.title,
      "quantity": _selectedProductSize,
      "myname": name
    });
  }
```

here's my firebase
[Here is the firebase ref](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbGwm.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to show the exact values of the variables you're passing to Firestore.  We can't see what `myid` and `widget.productId` are.  We also don't know what `cartRef` is.  I suggest reading this to learn how to create a complete minimal code sample: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error :`Invalid path (cart//Cart). Paths must not contain // in them` in your code seems you are passing `myId` as empty value now as I see it is empty in path that seems now `cart//Cart`
You should carefully check `myId` if that is correct passed.

Comment: I  fixed it by providing initial value  ==>
  Before   String myid= "";
After  String myid="initial"

Comment: Great to hear that. but your questions is closed? Please give me feedback if you mind. thanks.

Comment: If you mind please upvote my answer. Thanks.